# Bash. killing stack of functions selectively

Tags: bash, stack, return, exit

I want to know if there is some solution to kill some stack of functions without exiting the script. I have a menu, a submenu and a trap capturing function. I'll put a "reduced" example and try to explain my problem after that:

```
#!/bin/bash

function main_menu() {
    current_menu="main_menu"
    echo "this is main menu. Choose 1 to go to submenu1 or 2 to exit"
    read mainopt
    case ${mainopt} in
        1)
            submenu1
        ;;
        2)
            exit
        ;;
        *)
            invalid_opt
        ;;
    esac
    main_menu
}

function submenu1() {
    current_menu="submenu1"
    echo "this is submenu1. Choose 1 to operate or 2 to return to main menu"
    read submenu1opt
    case ${submenu1opt} in
        1)
            read -p "script operate"
        ;;
        2)
            return
        ;;
        *)
            invalid_opt
        ;;
    esac
    submenu1
}

function invalid_opt() {
    read -p "invalid option chosen. press Enter key to continue"
}

function capture_traps() {
    echo
    echo "you can't exit with Ctrl+c"
    launch_current_menu 
}

function launch_current_menu() {
    case ${current_menu} in
        "submenu1")
            submenu1
        ;;
        *)
            main_menu
        ;;
    esac
}

trap capture_traps INT
main_menu
```

Ok, to reproduce the problem:
-In main menu, press 1 to go to submenu
-In submenu1, Press Ctrl+c
-Then after the message "you can't exit with Ctrl+c", again in submenu1 press 2 to try to go to main menu. It doesn't get back.

The problem is it doesn't return because it has another submenu in stack. You must press "2" again to get back to main menu. How can avoid the problem? The desired behaviour (not sure if possible) is killing all the stack of functions in the capture_traps function except the last one. Is possible to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main_menu() {
    echo "Main menu"

    trap INT

    while true
    do
        read input
        submenu
    done
}

submenu() {
    echo "Submenu"
    trap main_menu INT

    while true
    do
        read input
        echo "$input"
    done
}

main_menu
```

This handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> differently depending on the context:

- In the main menu it exits the script
- In the submenu it returns to the main menu

---

Side note: Please beware that creating interactive menus in shell scripts is a pattern only ever seen in unrealistic exercises and misguided attempts to make scripts more palatable to users unfamiliar with *nix shells. If this is going to be production code you'll be doing yourself and the users a disservice if you follow this pattern. Reading up on [Bash input and output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput) is a very good place to start.

Comment: The "side note" is worth several upvotes, but I can only give one.

Comment: It's not what I'm asking for. Anyway, maybe your example could be an idea to restructure the script. The example I put is a reduced version, is much more complex. I discovered ${FUNCNAME[@]} to see the stack of functions... not sure (not tried yet) if I can terminate a function from another function, it could be nice. Thanks.